# Mysterious InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net

What does mean with type of exception?

"The Undo operation encountered a context that is different from what was applied in the corresponding Set operation."

I spent over 5 hours trying to find where exception arises((

update

Sorry for the misinformation..i found mistake..but can't figure out how that happens

In main thread created worker thread that create new form and calls form.showDialog..
After calling form.Close application dies:((

Comment: It would really help if you'd explain where the exception was coming from... what technologies you're using, what the code looks like, what the stack trace looks like etc.

Comment: If you spend 5 hours trying to find a solution, you should spend more than 1 minute phrasing your question. No one can help you with what you've written. Give code examples and tell us what you are doing!

Comment: I am using .net 4.0 framewwork
I can't find where exact exception arise becouse i only catch  exception as 'unhandled'
without any information of code line or e.t.c

Comment: That does not help. Give more details.

Comment: i am using ManualResetEvent class. Code sends message through the socket on server and wait response. If no response code sends message again.one second i post example of code

Comment: It's even more mysterious that you've posted a question like this without source code. If we can't reproduce the problem ourselves, we can't figure out the solution.

Comment: i am novice at with service sorry(

Comment: sorry for the misinformation..i found mistake..but can't figure out how that happens.

In main thread created worker thread that create new form and calls form.showDialog..
After calling form.Close application dies:((

Comment: Use `join` so the main thread waits for new one. Then exiting second thread won't terminate the application.

Answer (score 0):

An exception is a kind of message sent to informs that something bad has happened. It usually has extra information about the bad situation.

It's like a bubble coming from under the water to surface. If nobody `catch` it, then it is shown to you (here the name is `unhandled exception`).

You should avoid `unhandled exception`s in your code and think about all bad situations and do something for them. For example if your program is gonna write something on a CD and there's no CD in the CD-ROM, you should show a message to the user and tell him to put a CD in the CD-ROM. This would be something like this in your code:

```
try
{
    // Copy file to CD
    // Show message: File Copied successfully
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Something wrong happened: there's no CD in CD-ROM, CD has not enough space...
    // Show message: Cannot copy file!
}
```

In the above example `ex` is of type of `Exception` and has some details about the bad situation. As you see After the line `// Copy file to CD` I try to show a success message to the user. This is because as soon as we fail at the line `// Copy file to CD` program will resume from `catch` part, because we have got the bad situation and have some information about it. If you don't use `try/catch` in the above example, and use it in another code, the you have the chance to get the `exception` there before it becomes an `unhandled exception`.

Comment: i know how use try/catch but i can't find peace of code where exception may arises..for example if i wrap try/catch code that runs another thread and exception was thrown in another trhead try/cathc not will helped me(

Comment: Exceptions are thrown on the thread who has executed the buggy code. If you need to know about it from another thread you should use a shared object and signal the other thread that something wrong has happened.